YouTube Volume Randomly Resets to 50% in Firefox on Fedora
I’m experiencing a recurring issue where YouTube videos in Firefox keep resetting to 50% volume on Fedora (with PipeWire). I normally set the volume to 100% (both in the YouTube player and in the KDE mixer), but occasionally, YouTube drops back down to 50% on its own.
I’ve tried:

Switched to standard blocking
Verfied that media.default_volume is set to 1.0 (in about:config)
Clearing browser data and disabling all Firefox extensions
Switching to a brand-new Firefox profile
Checking KDE’s audio mixer (the volume shows 100% when I set YouTube to 100%, but moving the KDE slider doesn’t always reflect in YouTube’s internal slider)

Despite these steps, the problem still persists.
This happens most of the time when I have some YouTube Tabs open (but not visited them yet (with middle mouse click), close the browser and go to the videos.
I haven't experienced this on Brave or LibreWolf and also not on another video platform like odysee.
Also, if I reload the site it's back to 100%.
(Firefox 133.0.3 from Fedora)
